# kustomize: how to pass `newTag` as Label

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, kustomize, argocd

I am using https://kustomize.io/ have below is my kustomization.yaml file,

I would like to pass `newTag` image version to labels on `deployment.yaml` when i use ArgoCD to apply this file. Does anyone have any idea without using shell script to sed the `newtag` to deployment.yaml file.

deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: "apps/v1"
kind: "Deployment"
metadata:
  name: "hellowolrd"
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: aggregate
        appversion: ${newtag} <<<<<
```

kustomization.yaml

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
images:
- name: hellowolrd
  newName: hellowolrd
  newTag: 12345
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this directly with `newTag` value. However you can use a PatchTransformer built-in plugin to change `appversion` value.

Add this

```yaml
resources:
  - deployment.yaml
patches:
  - patch: |-
      - op: replace
        path: /spec/template/metadata/labels/appversion
        value: v2
    target:
      kind: Deployment
```

to your *kustomization.yaml*, and run `kustomize build`.
The result will look like this

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hellowolrd
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: aggregate
        appversion: v2
```

Yo ucan read more [here](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/guides/extending_kustomize/builtins/#_patchtransformer_).

Comment: This is a good one, but I would like to change only `kustomization.yaml` file.

Is it possible to pass `newTag` to `value: v2` like `value: images[helloworld].newTag`?

Comment: You have to add the code in first block to *kustomization.yaml* file, no need to create/change anything else. Unfortunately, you can't self-reference a value inside a file, and since `patch` block is a literal string, anything in `value` will be passed to generated yaml as-is

Answer (score 1):

An updated answer using Kustomize [replacements](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/kustomization/replacements/).

```yaml
images:
- name: my-registry-location
  newTag: 1.1.1

replacements:
  - source:
      kind: Deployment
      fieldPath: spec.template.spec.containers.[name=<container-name>].image
      options:
        delimiter: ":"
        index: 1 
    targets:
      - select:
          name: <deployment-name>
          kind: Deployment
        fieldPaths:
          - metadata.labels.[app.kubernetes.io/version]
          - spec.template.metadata.labels.[app.kubernetes.io/version] 
        options:
          create: true
```

Comment: I had no idea you could use delimiters in the replacements source. Nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a Component to do this by combining the label replacement (v2) with a ReplacementTransformer that copies the new label into the image tag.

https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/4174#issuecomment-917194980